# What's the difference between CILightenBlendMode and CIMaximumCompositing?

Tags: macos, image-processing, graphics, core-image

Core Image provides two filters, `CILightenBlendMode` and `CIMaximumCompositing`, which both appear to use the formula `outputColorComponent = max(backgroundColorComponent, foregroundColorComponent)`.  And from their respective descriptions in the [Core Image Filter Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html), it sounds like these two filters do exactly the same thing.

What's the difference between these two filters?  Why isn't there just a single filter?

(The same question applies also to the `CIDarkenBlendMode` and `CIMinimumCompositing` pair of filters.)

Comment: I don't have a definitive answer, but you are correct that they look identical, and appear to be implemented identically. As for why they have both? No idea.